# How to call get api in react js using ID?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch customer record using ID but it gives me error 404 and even if I try using like "https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/5" in browser it gives result only for ID 5 and below error message for other id

```
{
"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
"title":"Not Found",
"status":404,
"traceId":"|a1f6c563-4f8db349ec6c707f."
}
```

this is the call Customer. If I click on any edit it passes the ID but when It try to fetch the specific user data it gives me error. In onEditCustomer

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AddCustomer from './AddCustomer';

export default class Customer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        formClose:false,
        isAddCustomer:false,
        isEditCustomer:false,
        singleCustomer:{},
        users: []
    }
}

//fetch data 
componentDidMount() {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Origin','https://localhost:44387');

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        myHeader
    };

    fetch(customerApi, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                users: result,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
            });
        }
    )


}

//close form
closeForm = event => {
    this.props.closeCreateForm();
}

//New Customer record
onAddFormSubmit = data => {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'post',
        headers:myHeader,
        body:JSON.stringify(data)

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            console.log("Customer add result");
            console.log(result);
            this.setState({})
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )
}

//Edit customer record
onEditCustomer = custId => {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/';

    const customerRecord = new FormData();
    customerRecord.append("customerId", custId );

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'POST',
        headers:myHeader,
        body:customerRecord

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                singleCustomer:result,
                isEditCustomer:true,
                isAddCustomer:true
            })
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )

}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    let customerForm;
    if (this.state.isEditCustomer || this.state.isAddCustomer){
        customerForm = <AddCustomer onAddFormSubmit = {this.onAddFormSubmit} singleCustomer = {this.state.singleCustomer}/>
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <Table celled textAlign='center'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body >
                    {
                        users.map(user => (
                            <Table.Row key={user.customerId}>

                                <Table.Cell>{user.customerId}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.address}</Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='blue' onClick = {()=>this.onEditCustomer(user.customerId)}>Edit</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='red'>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                            </Table.Row>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table.Body>

                <Table.Footer>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='5'>
                            No of Pages
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Footer>
            </Table>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Here is ASP.NET Core controller for API

```
namespace CRUDReact.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataBaseContext _context;

    public CustomersController(DataBaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Customers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomer()
    {
        return await _context.Customer.ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET: api/Customers/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        var customer = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(id);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return customer;
    }

    // PUT: api/Customers/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer(int id, Customer customer)
    {
        customer.CustomerId = id;

        _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CustomerExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Customers
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        _context.Customer.Add(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.CustomerId }, customer);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Customers/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        var customer = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Customer.Remove(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return customer;
    }

    private bool CustomerExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Customer.Any(e => e.CustomerId == id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what ids show up in your database? Are you sure the id you are trying to access is in the database?

Comment: yes, The id I am calling is in database.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on `public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id) {` and send the id that you are trying to get with postman. And on the `Autos` prompt in visual studio, what values does it give you for `customer` properties, such as id value? And of course you will be reading values when the arrow hits `if (customer == null)`.

Comment: when you fetch the specific user data, you have to change the request to GET . In above code, you use POST method that why. `fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'POST',
        headers:myHeader,
        body:customerRecord

    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should update your endpoint to append customer ID?

```
const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers/' + custId;
```